# Find out how or where a program (script) is automatically starting at ubuntu 14 boot?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, startup, boot, autostart

Running Ubuntu 14.04, and I have a script that is being run automatically when I boot the machine. For the life of me, I can't remember how or where I did this.

I already checked:

- upstart (which doesn't seem to be available here, anyway)
- /etc/rc.local
- crontab (with @reboot)
- /etc/init
- /etc/init.d
- .config/autostart (doesn't exist btw)

It's a script of my own, so it's not some kind of malicious virus or malware or anything. I just can't remember how I did this, and would like to know.

It has a distinct name, e.g. like ~/MyScriptXYZ.sh so I could search for that, IF I know how or where..?? (I'm a novice linux user)

Comment: If the script is still running, or if you can edit it, use `pstree`; also run `grep -r MyScriptXYZ $HOME /etc`

Answer (score 2):

A few other places you can look:

`crontab -e` as your own user and as root (local user crontab)

`/etc/profile.d/` or `/etc/profile`

`~/.profile`

`~/.bashrc`

The last ditch attempt you can do is to `cd / && grep -R "MyScriptXYZ"` as root - this will take a while but will search all files on your computer for that reference :)

Answer (score 1):

So I stumbled across this question and I managed to solve it for myself: 
I was using Ubuntu (chroot) through the Linux Deploy Android app and I also couldn't find it. So to make the answer complete: ***Use pstree to locate and trace what is currently running and see where it's originating from.***

Following [Basile Starynkevitch](https://stackoverflow.com/users/841108/basile-starynkevitch)'s advice I managed to solve it by going to:
/home/[user]/.config/lxsession/LXDE/autostart and find it the code I added a while ago.